# HTML/CSS Beginner - Nesting <div> s within a <div> then applying positioning

Tags: css, positioning

I am trying to display a basic 4 block layout to the centre of the page. My current effort is utilising the following on the parent div (class=wrapper)

```
.wrapper
{
margin:0 auto;
width:960px;
}
```

However, although this then centres all child divs it does not allow me to position the child divs as per my desired layout i.e. having a block left:36px and top: 120px.

Any ideas how I can position child divs absolutely, but in relation to the central positioning of the .wrapper div?

Thanks.

Matt

Comment: can you be a little bit more precise with "a basic 4 block layout" (is it 2x2 table-cell like ...etc)?

Comment: May be some HTML would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To position the child divs in relation to the parent div (.wrapper), you can do something similar to:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
#child-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 36px;
}
```

You need to add `position: relative;` to the parent div so that while using `position: absolute;` on the child blocks, they will be positioned absolutely within the parent div.

See the example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Laxman13/gVytq/).

Also, for a quick start, [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position the child divs precisely (i.e. left: 36px; top: 120px;):

Add position: relative to the wrapper div, and position:absolute to the child divs.

The child divs will then be positioned 36 pixels from the left hand edge of the wrapper, and 120 pixels from the top. The wrapper div will be centred (horizontally) on the page.